# Why npm test commond fail with"Type ... is not assignable to type ..." in vue2 source code

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I `git clone` vue source code from github, and then I run `yarn` to install dependencies.
And the I run `npm test`,but test failed.

[image]

Anybody knows Why this error happened and how to fix it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because `vue`'s typescript version is [`3.6.4`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/612fb89/package.json#L139) but `@ts-expect-error` was introduced in [`typescript@3.9`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments).

You may run:

```sh
yarn upgrade typescript
```

inside the vue directory and try to run the tests again.